# django: one-to-many relation range

Tags: django

I have the following two models implemention one-to-many relation.

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    pass
class Item(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

For any Collection instance I want to know the latest and the first corresponding items.

I would like to obtain this Items at `models.Collection.objects.get(id=1)` using ***single SQL request***. I believe the request could use `JOIN` with subsequent min and max aggregations.

To operate with this first/latest objects I would like to use an interface like the following:

```
c = models.Collection.objects.get(id=1)
c.get_latest() # Item instance obtained in the previous line and stored in object c
c.get_first() # Item instance also
```

The question is how to merge the following three expressions to single SQL request:

```
Collection.objects.get(id=1)
Item.objects.filter(collection_id=1).latest('date')
Item.objects.filter(collection_id=1).earliest('date')
```

How could I ask Django to do it for me?

Comment: `Items.objects.filter(collection_id=1)`?

Comment: Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#latest reg. your edit

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of combining all three queries into one is by creating a large raw query that first gets your `Collection` and then the latest and earliest `Item`s. You would then, however not have one `Collection` and two `Item` objects, but instead one `Collection` object with additional attributes that you could read out. Not really the way I would go with this.

You can, however reduce this to two queries by using a raw query just for the items. Keep your

```
c = models.Collection.objects.get(id=1)
```

for the retrieval of the collection object. Then use the following raw query for the items:

```
i = Item.objects.raw('''
    SELECT * FROM <package_name>_item WHERE collection_id = %(collection_id)s ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM <package_name>_item WHERE collection_id = %(collection_id)s ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
''', {
    'collection_id': c.id,
})
```

(replace `<package_name>` by the name of the django app with the models)

I don't think this makes a lot of sense though, as the query essentially operates on the table twice. So you could probably split the query in two without a lot of performance loss.

There is a way to solve this in a single SQL Query (again wrap in the raw() statement):

```
SELECT * FROM <package_name>_item
WHERE collection_id = %(collection_id)s
AND (
    date = (
        SELECT max(date) FROM <package_name>_item
        WHERE collection_id = %(collection_id)s
    ) OR 
    date = (
        SELECT min(date) FROM <package_name>_item
        WHERE collection_id = %(collection_id)s
    )
)
```

This has one problem though: If multiple `Item`s exist with the min or max date, the query would return them all.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can merge the three queries, but you can try this.

```
items = Item.objects.filter(collection__id=1) # you have all items of collection whit ID = 1
```

remember django queries are lazy, so in the first line you dont hit the DataBase.

To get de last and first use:

```
first_item = items.first()
last_item = items.last()
```

Here you don´t hit DataBase, and you have first_item, last_item, and the collection object.

```
# firt_item
# last_item
# first_item.collection
```